# Python disable logging messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging

I have a program and I log different things throughout its execution. Now, this is all fine during debugging but when I ship it, obviously I would like the logging functions to not be called at all.

I remember there was a way to leave your logging calls in the code ant set some variable `__debug__` or something so that those logging calls are simply ignored, so they don't even create a stack frame and slow down the execution at runtime.

I'm pretty sure I have seen this before but I can't find it anywhere. How do I do this?

The best analogue to this would be C conditional compilation:

```
#define LOGGED
```

Now instead of this:

```
// code...

log(stuff);

// code...
```

I can do this:

```
// code...

#ifdef LOGGED
    log(stuff);
#endif

// code...
```

The first option calls the log function every time, even if it's not displayed, and in a language like python, where function calls tend to be expensive, especially in tight loops, i would like to not clog the program with lots of them.

The second option is better because unless `LOGGED` is defined, the `log(stuff)` call will not even be compiled, it will be completely ignored.

I would like a way to do this in python because in my case, the difference between logging and no logging is about a 50% performance difference.

Comment: You need the `logging` module. Your log functions will still be called but they return quickly if the severity of the message does not match the log level.

Comment: @BoarGules They return quickly but in Python the building of a new stack frame for a function call is very slow. As I said, I have tried to do straight logging and the performance difference between with and without logging was 40-50%. That's not exactly "quickly", sadly...

Comment: Generally logging calls do a lot of string formatting of messages, and that is very slow. By eliminating the logging calls you have not necessarily demonstrated that the function calls are the whole problem: the computation of the parameters could be making a significant contribution.

Comment: @BoarGules I have also tried to do a custom logger with some kind of conditional compilation using a bool `LOGGED` variable and a custom logging function defined like this: `if LOGGED: def log(*args): # call the logging module here # ; else: def log(*args): pass` effectively replacing the logging function with a blank one and the performance difference between the genuine function and a blank one was small, the string formatting in the logging function made the program only about 5-10% slower than the blank function. At least in my case excessive function calls are a problem.

Comment: Then your only option is to preprocess your code and put a `#` before each log function call, which is pretty close to what the C preprocessor would do.